# Solving a difference equation for coin toss sequence probabilities

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I want to solve the following difference equation:

$$b_n-b_{n-1} = \frac{1}{8}(1-b_{n-3})$$

I tried to solve it similar to the solution of Fibonacci sequence [here](https://mathsbyagirl.wordpress.com/2016/11/21/fibonacci-sequence-with-differential-equations/), but when I try to assume the solution will be of the form $l^n$, I end up with the following polynomial:

$$l^{n-3}(l^3-l^2+\frac{1}{8}) = \frac{1}{8}$$

Unlike in the Fibonacci sequence, we don't get a polynomial equation that can be easily solved and independent of $n$.

Any other strategy to solve this?

---

The reason I care about this difference equation is that it describes the probability I will get two consecutive heads on the $n$th toss of a fair coin.

Let $a_n$ be the probability that I'll reach two consecutive heads on the $n$th toss.

We know that at the time when I reach my goal on the $n$th toss, the last two tosses I saw would have both been heads.

Also, the third-from-final toss would have had to be a tails (otherwise, I would have won one toss earlier). The probability of this sequence
of THH is $\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{8}$.

Before these three tosses, my probability of winning would have been by definition, $a_{n-3}$. But if I am to win in the $n$th toss,
I need to exclude that event. And similarly $a_{n-4}$ and so on. This means:

$$a_n=\frac{1}{8}\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n-3} a_i\right)$$

Now let's define:

$$b_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i$$

which represents the probability you would have won *by* the $n$th toss.

Plugging this equation into the previous one we get:

$$b_n-b_{n-1} = \frac{1}{8}(1-b_{n-3})$$

Comment: This thing is done exactly like 2nd order linear differential equations. First, find the solution for the homogeneous part then take an ansatz for the inhomogeneous part. The sum of the homogeneous and particular solution is the general one

Comment: Thanks, that is a promising direction. Let me try. To speed my progress, do you happen to have a link to this approach in action on some other problem? No worries if not.

Comment: Actually no, I just remember reading it somewhere.. I will try to sketch a rough answer.

Comment: $$
b_n = 1 + A\left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{4} \right)^n + B\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{4} \right)^n + C 2^{-n}
$$

Comment: Woah, how did you get those coefficients? How? How? How?

Comment: It is fairly simple by using a [Z-transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform). I can post the full solution if you are interested

Comment: Yes, please! I am very interested. I know those coefficients are right, but that is via a completely different approach to the problem (which does not involve the difference equation) and highly unlikely you got them the same way. Very curious to learn about this new method.

Comment: Yeah even me, I don't know about the z-transform way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The homogeneous part of $b_{n}−b_{n−1}=\frac{1}{8}(1−b_{n−3})$ is given by:
$$8b_{n}-8b_{n-1}+b_{n-3}=0$$

So the characteristic equation is given by:

$$8l^3-8l^2+1=0$$

The roots are given by $l=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4}, \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4},\frac{1}{2}$

And the answer can be taken as a constant: $b_n=c$. Substituting in 
$$8b_n+8b_{n-1}-b_{n-3}=1$$
We have $c=\frac{1}{15}$

Therefore the general solution can be written as:

$$b_n=\sigma_1\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{4}\right)^n+ \sigma_2\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{4}\right)^n+\sigma_3\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n+\frac{\sigma_4}{15}.$$

And for the two consecutive heads problem, we can use the first few values in the sequence $b_n$ in particular, $b_0=0$, $b_1=0$, $b_2=0.25$ and $b_3=0.375$ to get $\sigma_1 = -1.1708$, $\sigma_2=1.708$, $\sigma_3=0$, $\sigma_4=15$

Comment: Thanks! Not clear about this part - And the ansatz can be taken as $b_n=c$. What is $c$ here?

Comment: Ah I see now, just a constant. Thanks!

Comment: It's a guess solution an ansatz for the inhomogeneous case. You may use $b_n =c2^{-n}$ and see whats the solution. It's just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

I have another approach to this I just worked out. Here, we try to use express the recurrence as a system of linear equations. Then, we leverage the eigen values of the matrix associated with the matrix of this linear system.

So far, we have only one equation. This is:

$$b_n -b_{n-1} + \frac{1}{8}b_{n-3} = \frac{1}{8}$$
To form a linear system, we need two more equations. Let's take some dummy equations.
$$b_{n-1}=b_{n-1}$$

$$b_{n-2}=b_{n-2}$$

Now, we can express this system in matrix form.

$$\left( \begin{array}{c}
  b_n \\
  b_{n-1}\\
  b_{n-2}\\
  \end{array} \right) = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
  1 & 0 & -\frac{1}{8} & \\
  1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 1 & 0\\
  \end{array} \right) \left( \begin{array}{c}
  b_{n-1} \\
  b_{n-2}\\
  b_{n-3}\\
  \end{array} \right) + \left( \begin{array}{c}
  \frac{1}{8} \\
  0\\
  0\\
  \end{array} \right)$$

Now let:
$\beta_n = \left(\begin{array}{c}
  b_n \\
  b_{n-1}\\
  b_{n-2}\\
  \end{array} \right)$, $\gamma = \left(\begin{array}{c}
  \frac{1}{8} \\
  0\\
  0\\
  \end{array} \right)$ and $M = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
  1 & 0 & -\frac{1}{8} & \\
  1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 1 & 0\\
  \end{array} \right)$.

We then get:

$$\beta_n = M \beta_{n-1} + \gamma$$
$$=M(M \beta_{n-2}+\gamma) + \gamma$$

$$=M^2 \beta_{n-2} + (I+M)\gamma$$

Extending this all the way we get:

$$\beta_n = M^{n-2}\beta_{2} + (I+M+M^2+ \dots + M^{n-3})\gamma$$

Now, assuming $M$ is diagonalizable (which it is) we can say:

$$M=E\Lambda E^{-1}$$
And this would imply:
$$M^n = E \Lambda^n E^{-1}$$

So we get:
$$\beta^n = E\Lambda^{n-2}E^{-1}\beta_2 + E(I+\Lambda+\Lambda^2+\dots+\Lambda^{n-3})E^{-1}\gamma$$

Now, if $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$ happen to be the eigen values of $M$ then,
$$\Lambda = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
  \lambda_1 & 0 & 0 & \\
  0 & \lambda_2 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & \lambda_3\\
  \end{array} \right)$$

and,

$$(I+\Lambda+\Lambda^2 + \dots + \Lambda^{n-3}) = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
  \frac{1-\lambda_1^{n-2}}{1-\lambda_1} & 0 & 0 & \\
  0 & \frac{1-\lambda_2^{n-2}}{1-\lambda_2} & 0\\
  0 & 0 & \frac{1-\lambda_3^{n-2}}{1-\lambda_3}\\
  \end{array} \right)$$

Using these, it is easy to see that:

$$\beta_n = c_0 + c_1 \lambda_1^{n-2} + c_2 \lambda_2^{n-2} + c_3 \lambda_3^{n-2}$$

And the eigen values happen to be: $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3 = \frac{\phi}{2}$, $\frac{1-\phi}{2}$, $0.5$.